# Subset data frame for specific dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame like this one

```
yr06 = as.Date("2006-07-01")+0:100
yr07 = as.Date("2007-07-11")+0:108
Date = c(yr06,yr07)
Data = c(0:100,0:108)
df = data.frame(Date,Data)
```

I want to subset for just these dates

```
D6 = as.Date("2006-08-20")+0:38
D7 = as.Date("2007-08-20")+0:44
```

Comment: `subset(df, Date %in% c(D6, D7))`

Answer (score 2):

```
sub.df = subset(df, as.Date(Date) >= '2006-08-20' & 
                    as.Date(Date) <= '2006-09-27' | 
                    as.Date(Date) >= '2007-08-20' & 
                    as.Date(Date) <= '2007-10-03')
```

is my clumsy solution.

Comment: I'd sprinkle in a few parentheses in there - that looks dangerous.

Comment: @eddi: parentheses are for wimps!